# msg.sender.balance returns a strange number

Tags: solidity

From a JS web3 file, I am calling a simple function that returns the wallet balance.

```
function readCustomerBalance() public view returns (uint) {
  return msg.sender.balance;
}
```

Works fine in Remix.

Trying to calling it via js file to display the wallet balance in my website I get a weird number.

This is the js function:

```
function getCstValue(){
  contractInstance.methods.readCustomerBalance().call().then(function(res){
    console.log(res);
  });
}
```

My wallet balance is: `31.3898ETH`

The return value is: `180143953705057640000000000`

I am getting crazy right now. Any idea??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you have getter method for returning ETH balance when web3 have this function inside the library? Example:

```
web3.eth.getBalance('0x4bc2612caeb83f84e3cccf9edc52417738b3fae2', function(error, result) {
    if(error) {
        console.log(error);
    } else {
        console.log(web3.utils.fromWei(result));
    }
});
```

Comment: I did not know about it. thanks a lot!!

Comment: Yes, now if you don't need that getter method inside your contact for conditions you can remove it. You should always keep the smart contract simple as possible. Good luck!